# Update to version 2.2 on my HTC Hero Android 1.5 phone

Tags: 2.2-froyo, updates, 1.5-cupcake

Currently I am using HTC Hero with Android 1.5 and as we know right now Android 2.2 (Froyo) has been released, so i am planning to upgrade from 1.5 to 2.2.

Regarding updating, I have the following questions:

1. How do I update it?
2. Is there any selection options provided to update? For example I want to update my 1.5 to 2.1 instead of 2.2, 2.0 or anything else.
3. Are there any issues that have already occurred with Android 2.2?
4. What if I want to down-grade to lower version, is it possible? (i.e. rollback to older version)

Comment: Please clarify, are you referring to the SDK, Android development environment, or are you referring to the OS running on your phone? Two entirely different things.

Comment: @Webs i am talking about updation of my Android phone's OS (i.e. SDK) from 1.5 to 2.2

Comment: Ah yes, well the Hero cannot be updated past 2.1. That is as far as Sprint and HTC have gone. Just go to HTC's website and download the update, plug your phone in and have at it. Keep in mind you might lose settings and apps you downloaded. But updating is a good idea. The only way to get 2.2 on a Hero would be to root it. But most 2.2 roms are not fully functioning with everything in the Hero.

Comment: @webs i dont know anything about "root" the phone , what is the meaning of "root" and what are the probable advantages of "Root" phone ?

Comment: @Paresh, If you do not know anything about rooting your phone you may want to take some time to read about it before attempting. A lot of new people have trouble understanding some of the concepts so make sure you read a lot before diving in. Check out XDA Forums (http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=643) for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, if you were running SDK 1.6 or later you could just update without installing a new SDK. But for 1.5 you need to install a new SDK. Per this link from Google http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html (see quoted text below)...

How ever, you can backup your projects and move them into the new SDK environment. So it looks like all may not be lost. Just read that link above pretty thoroughly.

> Updating?
>
> If you are currently using the Android
>   1.6 SDK or later and want to update to the latest tools or platforms, you do
>   not need to install a new SDK.
>   Instead, you can simply update the
>   individual components in your SDK
>   using the Android SDK and AVD Manager
>   tool. For information about how to do
>   that, see Updating SDK Components
>
> If you are using Android 1.5 SDK or
>   earlier, you should install a new SDK
>   as described in this document and move
>   your application projects to the new
>   SDK environment.

Comment: @Webs i am talking about update sdk on my HTC Hero phone ...is this information helpful ??

Comment: @Paresh: the SDK is "Software Development Kit". I think you've confused that with the version of Android running on your phone.

Comment: Ah yes, we need some more clarification.